# Arrow in dropdown menu toggle not appearing right away but instead shows later when page is refreshed

Tags: wordpress, elementor

The website is [thekeygroupohio.com](https://thekeygroupohio.com/)

When you go the website the arrow in the menu doesn't show right away in the homepage. It takes at least an hour and refresh to actually see it but it shows right away on other page.

To replicate this, you can clear the cookies and site data for the site and refresh and the arrow in the menu does not display right away but if you click on any other pages aside from the homepage, it appears right away.

I minified the css and js through the litespeed cache and but it doesn't work.

I disabled CDN from hostinger - its a wordpress website using free elementor builder. Then I deactivated litespeed cache and it does the same.

So I reactivated them back and it still does the same.

Elementor and wordpress are up to date.